# How to enable phpmyadmin on virtual server in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I can access localhost/phpmyadmin but can't access www.project.com/phpmyadmin. 'www.project.com' is my virtual server. While trying to access www.project.com/phpmyadmin, it gave me 404 error. I've created symbolic link of phpmyadmin folder in root directory of virtual server.

I've mentioned location of /phpmyadmin on /etc/nginx/sites-available/project.com. 'project.com' is configuration file of nginx to add virtual server.

Here is the code of project.com

```
server {

    listen *:80;
    listen [::]:80;



    root /home/dell/Projects/site/project;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.project.*;

    access_log /home/dell/Projects/site/project/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/dell/Projects/site/project/logs/error.log;

    location /phpmyadmin {     
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;

            root /usr/share/;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }


        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root /usr/share/;
        }
    }
    location /phpMyAdmin {
        rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html{}

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Here is configuration of /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   dell-Inspiron-5423
127.0.1.1   www.project.com


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 version.

Do I need to configure config.inc.php? I viewed other similar post too but that didn't help.

Comment: Possibly the problem is the symbolic link, check for the [disable_symlinks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks) directives.

Comment: @HBruijn By default, disable_symlinks is off. Do I need to specify it again?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's not a problem, but if anyone can point out documentation to support the use of multiple lines for a single IP in the hosts file I'd be interested to see that.  It appears to be supported on ubuntu, but is not covered by the man page.  I seem to remember it being a windows extension?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using location within location, you don't need the full url. A bit more info on that [here](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,174517,174534#msg-174534).

The config below may not be the most optimal possible (do you need to allow only listed extensions for a particular reason?), but it should work.

Note that of course your phpmyadmin will have to be located in `usr/share/phpmyadmin` folder for php to work (since `$document_root` refers to `root /usr/share;` and won't automatically work if you will use `alias`.

```
location /phpmyadmin {     
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /usr/share/;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        root /usr/share/;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: I'm no top notch expert, so I can't go into particular detail why exactly it didn't work - sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that doesn't seem to bring any change. It still gives 404 error. Do I need to configure config.ini.php also?

Comment: Can you verify the symlink works properly and is accessible by the nginx user?

Comment: No, that's not the problem